# Gigabyte GA-H61M-S2PV Mother Board Cant See XFX Radeon HD 6870

Tags: windows-7, graphics-card, motherboard

Gigabyte GA-H61M-S2PV mother board isn't seeing an XFX Radeon HD 6870 graphics card. Other cards work on the system and the card works on other systems. I have set the graphics slot in the bios to PCI and it keeps reverting to auto. I am using windows 7. I have also ran the drivers and it does not see the device.

Comment: Settings the graphics to PCI is a mistake, once you place a graphics card into the your PCI express slot, it should detect it and switch over (assuming your motherboard has on board video). if its not, then obviously they are not compatible with each other, return the card or the motherboard and start over.

Comment: I cant, I have had this card for a few years and have been waiting for a power supply. Got any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If the Motherboard Works with other video cards. 
And the Video card works with other Motherboards, 
but don't work with each other, then the setup is simply not going to work. I've personally never heard of this happening since pci x16 was introduced.

The only thing i could recommend is updating the BIOS, check your motherboards manufacture website on how to do so. Doing this might update the compatibility list on the motherboard or fix any bugs that might cause that video card not to be detected on this specific motherboard.

Comment: I have already updated the bios and it is a pretty good board got any other ideas?

Comment: nope, you can wait for someone else to maybe have a better answer, but i'm pretty sure it's not going to work, you can try calling your video card company and ask them, that's your probably your last best hope.